# Request parameters are unavailable in servlet

Tags: spring, servlets, http-request-parameters

I can't read parameters from HttpServletRequest:

I tried with this method but not working.
public FormData readFormData(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException, ParseException
    {
        FormData formData = null;
        Enumeration paramNames = request.getParameterNames();

```
    if(paramNames.hasMoreElements())
        formData = new FormData();

    while(paramNames.hasMoreElements()) 
    {
        String paramValue = null; 
        String paramName = (String)paramNames.nextElement();
        //LOGGER.info("paramName :: " + paramName);
        String[] paramValues = request.getParameterValues(paramName);
        // Read single valued data
        if (paramValues.length == 1) {
            paramValue = paramValues[0];
            /*if (paramValue.length() == 0)
                LOGGER.info("<i>No Value</i>");
            else
                LOGGER.info("paramValue :: "+paramValue);*/
        } else {
            // Read multiple valued data
            /*for(int i=0; i < paramValues.length; i++) {
                LOGGER.info("<li>" + paramValues[i]+ "</li>");
            }*/
        }

        String key = paramName;
        if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("firstname"))
            formData.setFirstName(paramValue);
        if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("lastname"))
            formData.setLastName(paramValue);
        if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("username"))
            formData.setUserName(paramValue);
        if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("appusername"))
            formData.setAppUserName(paramValue);
        if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("time"))
        {
            Date time = dateFormatter.parse(paramValue);
            formData.setTime(time);
        }
        if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("authhash"))
            formData.setAuthHash(paramValue);
        if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("mandate"))
            formData.setMandate(paramValue);            
    }


    return formData;
}
```

`paramNames.hasMoreElements()` has a false value  !!

Parameters are visible with chrome inspector :

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7gDfH.png

Comment: Did you call `request.getInputStream()` or `request.getReader()` somewhere before the given code snippet? Remove that line.

Comment: Post your all controller or servlet not a snippet. And you are using GET or POST in your form action?